# Convert UTF-8 to ANSI

Tags: powershell, character-encoding

I am trying to convert UTF-8 to ANSI files. With little bit of knowledge and help of Google I found one line to convert SINGLE file

```
Get-Content C:\Output2\PA01.094 | Set-Content C:\Output\PA01094 -Encoding Ascii
```

Now I want to convert all UTF-8 files in a folder to another folder without changing filename.

Answer (score 6):

The following will read all files in `$sourceFolder` and re-create them under `$destFolder` encoded as ASCII.

```
$sourceFolder = "c:\temp\src"
$destFolder = "c:\temp\dst"

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder | 
    foreach-object {
        get-content $_.FullName | Set-content -Path ( Join-Path $destFolder $_.Name ) -Encoding ASCII
    }
```

N.B. This code DOES NOT verify the encoding of the original file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use code like below. Modify Get-ChildItem as required to specify files you need.

```
$sourcePath = "C:\source"
$destinationPath = "C:\output"
if (!(Test-Path $destinationPath))
{
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $destinationPath
}
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -File | ForEach-Object {
 Write-Host "Converting $_" 
 $content = Get-Content $_.FullName
 Set-content (Join-Path -Path $destinationPath -ChildPath $_) -Encoding Ascii -Value $content
}
```

ASCII encoding cannot handle all characters that UTF8 or other Unicode encodings can handle, character that can't be translated may result in ? in output file.

To check encoding of output you can use PowerShell.

For example for a text file created in Notepad that says "Hello, World!"

The following encodings will produce these results. Note start of UTF-8 has special characters, these indicate file is UTF-8, not the default Save format in Notepad.

```
PS C:\support> [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:\support\helloworld_ansi.txt")
    72
    101
    108
    108
    111
    44
    32
    87
    111
    114
    108
    100
    33
    PS C:\support> [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:\support\helloworld_unicode.txt")
    255
    254
    72
    0
    101
    0
    108
    0
    108
    0
    111
    0
    44
    0
    32
    0
    87
    0
    111
    0
    114
    0
    108
    0
    100
    0
    33
    0
    PS C:\support> [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:\support\helloworld_utf8.txt")
    239
    187
    191
    72
    101
    108
    108
    111
    44
    32
    87
    111
    114
    108
    100
    33
    PS C:\support>
```

Comment: This will overwrite the original files. Request is to write files to another folder.

Comment: Change set-content to wherever you want to write the files, adding example

Comment: A bit bloody cheeky. Your initial answer missed the point of the question. When I point it out, you rip off my answer. Nice.

Comment: I didn't even see your answer, I misread the question initially I thought it said to overwrite the existing files. I still had the page open.

Comment: Thank you all its script runs and put file in destination folder but not converting the file

Comment: Thanks You All Script Runs fine and puts file in destination folder but dont think its converting file because when open file file with notepad still says UTF-8...........

Comment: Also its adding ????? beginning of file and adding ????? end of the file

Comment: I would not trust Windows Notepad. Load the file into a hex editor and look at the first few bytes. If the first byte is actually the first character of the your file, then it's worked. If you see a Byte Order Mark (e.g. 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF), then it's still UTF8.

Comment: I added example code how to check the actual encoding with PowerShell.

Comment: Note not all UTf8 encoded files have a BOM header, but ones generated from Notepad. IT should be noted that UTF8 encoding standards do not reccomoend this 3 byte header for UTF8 encoded files, but ones generated from Notepad do have them; generated elsewhere it may not.

Comment: Tried to explicitly specify the encoding in    `Get-Content -Encoding UTF8` ? Also ASCII will not display all charcters like ü in german. Try `Set-Content -Encoding Default `